# how to get the values of multidimensional array

Tags: ajax, cakephp, search

how to get the values of multidimensional array.
code//

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [City] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Nagpur
                    [id] => 20299
                )

            [Branch] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                            [country_id] => 41
                            [state_id] => 102
                            [city_id] => 20299
                            [title] => Geotech Services Ltd.


                        )

                )


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [City] => Array
                (
                    [title] => kolapur
                    [id] => 20300
                )


        )

)
```

Here I want to get the only values if cities(title) so plz tel  me how to fetch in cakephp..
Thanks in advance

Comment: set your $this->City->recursive = -1; before find operation'

Comment: I get the answer -1. I want the all cities to store in another  single array

Comment: And whats that mean? If this approach don't solve your problem then update your question with your controller code.... Let us see what you are doing..

Answer (score 1):

Thus you finding as recursive so all related data is fetched with City. 
To disable this recursion, you need to set `$recursive = -1;`

You can do this by many ways--

1. place `$this->City->recursive = -1;` before find operation
2. place `recursive => -1` on find overation
3. Globally set `public $recursive = -1`; on AppModel.php

And if you read from this array its simple and basic programming operation...

```
foreach($cities as $city){
  echo $city['City']['title']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using cakePHP what you're trying to do is usually achieved using [Hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html)

Assuming `$your_array` contains the data, then you have to do:

```
$cities = Hash::extract($your_array, '{n}.City.title');
```